# In comments i'm adding @username but it isn't adding up eventually.Why?

Tags: discussion, comments

I'm adding @username (the user to whom i'm replying to) in comments but in the added comment it isn't showing up.

Does that mean my comment will not be notified to the user as a message in his  inbox?

Has happened more than once until now. What is the reason?

Comment: This could be due to you were trying to add name of "person" in comments under the "same person's answer". For example, if i wrote a answer and in comments under my answer, there no need to mention @Anil as by default it notifies me

Comment: Also couple of other facts, you can only tag one user in one comment. That is, you cannot say @rick and @ rickross. Only the first one will be taken into account. Secondly, you can only tag a user if he/she has commented in that post before. For example, if I tag @ user1013499 here, they would never get notified, even if they exist as a user on this site, because they have not commented here before. All the best!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Rickross](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/4732/rickross) the post owner in a comment is not necessary. If comments are only between you and the post-owner, if nobody is commenting, then an @username to the post owner at the beginning of a comment will be removed.
if only you and the author have commented on the post so far, the @name will be automatically removed from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no value.

> Why do some names not appear in the auto-complete box?
>
> *The auto-complete box can determine when an @name would not be necessary to trigger a notification and in that case will not include the user in the list.
> Additionally, only users who have commented on the post are ever populated into the list. Editors and other users from the post's history will never appear there, even if they are able to be notified by typing manually.*

All the things are taken from **META.SE**

You can see it clearly i just typed two text in the comment box and an auto complete box appear on your [Question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10565/which-scripture-is-the-source-for-this-achamanam/10568#10568) [image]

Here is my [Question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6803/why-brihaspati-got-insulted-by-gods) and i am trying to add @Keshav but an auto complete box ain't apear.[image]

*It's Clear that We can't Add @username on answer of our own questions but we can do this on another one's questions and answers:*

[image]

Comment: Ok.I have understood now.

Comment: Cool, I thought my browser was acting up :P